# Fade In Action not Working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I have SplashScreen where I load my assets and show an image

Everything works well but fadeIn Action doesn't work although fadeOut works

Here is my code :

```
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage();
    Texture splashTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("splash.png"));
    splash = new Image(splashTexture);
    splash.setPosition(Constants.WIDTH/2 - splash.getWidth()/2, Constants.HEIGHT/2 - splash.getHeight()/2);
    stage.addActor(splash);
    splash.getColor().a = 0;
    SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction(Actions.fadeIn(2.0f), Actions.delay(2.0f), 

Actions.fadeOut(2.0f), Actions.run(new Runnable() { 
    @Override public void run() { gameMain.setScreen(new MenuScreen(gameMain, null, true)); } }));
    splash.addAction(Actions.parallel(Actions.run(new Runnable() { 
    @Override public void run() { Assets.load(); 
    } }), sequenceAction)); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Actions.fadeOut(0f)` just before fadeIn action

```
SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction(Actions.fadeOut(0f),Actions.fadeIn(2.0f), ...);
```

or

instead `splash.getColor().a = 0;` use `splash.setColor(1,1,1,0);`